# How to show that $\sqrt{x}$ grows faster than $\ln{x}$.

Tags: calculus

So I have the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\left(\frac{1}{2-\frac{3\ln{x}}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)=\frac{1}2,$$ I now want to motivate why $(3\ln{x}/\sqrt{x})\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty.$ I cam up with two possibilites:

1. Algebraically it follows that $$\frac{3\ln{x}}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{3\ln{x}}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x}}}=\frac{3\sqrt{x}\ln{x}}{x}=3\sqrt{x}\cdot\frac{\ln{x}}{x},$$
   Now since the last factor is a standard limit equal to zero as $x$ approaches infinity, the limit of the entire thing should be $0$. However, isn't it a problem because $\sqrt{x}\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ gives us the indeterminate value $\infty\cdot 0$?
2. One can, without having to do the arithmeticabove, directly motivate that the function $f_1:x\rightarrow \sqrt{x}$ increases faster than the function $f_2:x\rightarrow\ln{x}.$ Is this motivation sufficient? And, is the proof below correct?

We have that $D(f_1)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$ and $D(f_2)=\frac{1}{x}$. In order to compare these two derivateives, we have to look at the interval $(0,\infty).$ Since $D(f_1)\geq D(f_2)$ for $x\geq4$, it follows that $f_1>f_2, \ x>4.$

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x}}\stackrel{x\mapsto z^2}{=} 2 \lim_{z\to +\infty}\frac{\log z}{z} \stackrel{z\mapsto e^t}{=} 2\lim_{t\to +\infty}\frac{t}{e^t} = 0 $$
since, for instance, $e^t\geq 1+t$ implies $e^t = \left(e^{t/2}\right)^2 \geq \left(1+\frac{t}{2}\right)^2 $.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. This is a standard result from high school
2. If you nevertheless want to deduce it from the limit of $\dfrac{\ln x}x$, use the properties of logarithm:
   $$\frac{\ln x}{\sqrt x}=\frac{2\ln(\sqrt x)}{\sqrt x}\xrightarrow[\sqrt x\to\infty]{}2\cdot 0=0$$

Answer (score 6):

When the numerator and denominator both go to $\infty$, it is in [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), we can use  [L'Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln x}{\sqrt{x}} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1/x}{1/(2\sqrt{x})}=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{2}{\sqrt{x}}=0$$

Comment: Sorry, I'n my school we are not allowed to use L'hopital's rule.

Answer (score 2):

For any $a > c > 0, x > 1$,
we have

$\begin{array}\\
\ln(x)
&=\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}\\
&\lt\int_1^x \frac{dt}{t^{1-c}}\\
&=\int_1^x t^{c-1}dt\\
&=\dfrac{t^c}{c}\big|_1^x\\
&=\dfrac{x^c-1}{c}\\
&<\dfrac{x^c}{c}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^a}
&<\dfrac1{x^a}\dfrac{x^c}{c}\\
&=\dfrac{x^{c-a}}{c}\\
&\to 0
\qquad\text{as } x \to \infty
\text{ since } a > c\\
\end{array}
$

For your case,
where $a = \frac12$,
we can choose
$c = \frac14$
to get
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^{1/2}}
\lt\dfrac{x^{\frac14-\frac12}}{\frac14}
=4x^{-\frac14}
\to 0
$.

In general
we can choose
$c = a/2$
to get
$\dfrac{\ln(x)}{x^{a}}
\lt\dfrac{x^{a/2-a}}{a/2}
=\dfrac{2}{ax^{a/2}}
\to 0
$.